# How do I import a PKCS12 certificate into a java keystore?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool

I have a certificate in PKCS12 format. How do I import it into a java keystore file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Import alice.p12 into bob.jks**

```bash
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore alice.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore bob.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: Worked for me (JDK 1.8.0_211)

Comment: Could you please advice what shall I do with JSK storage?
Shall I put into `.../jre/lib/security/` ?