# Not able to generate stubs from WSDL

Tags: wsdl, java-17

Back in the day, I was able to generate the stubs from WSDL using eclipse no plugins there, and wsimport, etc. seems everything has changed. At that time I was using JDK 5 adding certificates also was an easy process for me.

now I am using java 17. and my WSDL URL is not public so I had to install the certificates I did and was able to run the URL from the browser and I can see the APIs.
now the problem is I am trying to generate the stubs using different approaches I have tried from SOAP UI, apache CXF, wsimport.

every approach I failed. however, I spend little effort on wsimport approach. while I am doing this I am getting the following error in the console.

[image]

to solve this issue i found something from google and tried the following command.

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias superadmin -file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\lib\security\superadmin.cer 
-keystore “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\lib\security\cacerts” -storepass changeit
```

the first one is my certificate which i kept in that location.
and the second one is JDK provided one.

when i run the above command i was getting the below error in the console.

[image]

any help would really appriciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, edit your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import a PKCS12 certificate into a java keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116235/how-do-i-import-a-pkcs12-certificate-into-a-java-keystore)

Comment: keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore alice.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore bob.jks -deststoretype JKS-- i have reframed the command which you suggested (from the link) i replaced the alice.p12 with my superadmin.p12, what should i take in place of bob.jks

Comment: It should be the cacerts. Note take a backup of cacerts first.

Comment: is it feasible with java 17, bcz i have run all commands and followed all the steps but still same error.